# Dynamic select with onchange function calling to jquery with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery, dynamic

PLease help , I used some examples to build dynamic select, but it does not seem to work , nevertheless in console I can see 200 status, I am not fluent so please please help, The problem is that list in the select will not decrease, it shows same options after choosing previos

index.html.erb

```
  <%= collection_select(nil, :site_id,  @sites,  :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Site"}, { :id => "sites_select"}) %>
                            <br/>
                    <%= collection_select(nil, :floor_id, @floors, :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Floor"}, {:id => "floors_select"}) %>
                    <br/>
                    <%= collection_select(nil, :pod_id, @pods, :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a pod"}, {:id => "pods_select"}) %>
                    <script>
                          $(document).ready(function() {
                            $('#sites_select').change(function() {
                              $.ajax({
                                url: "<%= update_floors_path %>",
                                data: {
                                  site_id : $('#sites_select').val()
                                },
                                dataType: "script"
                              });
                            });
                            $('#floors_select').change(function() {
                              $.ajax({
                                url: "<%= update_pods_path %>",
                                data: {
                                  floor_id : $('#floors_select').val()
                                },
                                dataType: "script"
                              });
                            });
                          });
                        </script>
```

devices_controller.rb

```
  def update_floors
# updates floors and pods based on genre selected
site = Site.find(params[:site_id])
# map to name and id for use in our options_for_select
@floors = site.floors.map{|a| [a.name, a.id]}.insert(0, "Select a Floor")
@pods   = site.pods.map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}.insert(0, "Select a Pod")

end

def update_pods
# updates pods based on floor selected
floor = Floor.find(params[:floor_id])
@pods =floor.pods.map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}.insert(0, "Select a Pod")
end
```

update_floors.js.erb

```
$('#floors_select').html("<%= escape_javascript(options_for_select(@floors)) %>");
$('#pods_select').html("<%= escape_javascript(options_for_select(@pods)) %>");
```

update_pods.js.erb
    $('#pods_select').html("<%= escape_javascript(options_for_select(@pods)) %>");

routes.rb

```
  get 'devices/update_floors', :as => 'update_floors'
      get 'devices/update_pods', :as => 'update_pods'
      root :to => "devices#index"
```

Appreciate any suggestion
Thank you,
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems new loaded JavaScript not adding effects to parent page. Why not do the $().html inside the Ajax success callback. And make the update.js.html page only contains the options for select. Should work.

javascript:

```
$("#sites_select").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: your_url,
      //orther options ...
      success: function(data){
          $("#floors_select").html(data);
      }
    });

});
```

and in your update_floors.js.html

```
<%=options_for_select(@floors)%>
```

Do the same for update pods. :)

Comment: Started GET "/devices/update_pods" for 10.110.13.24 at 2012-12-12 13:41:25 -0800
Processing by DevicesController#update_pods as */*
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Floor without an ID):
  app/controllers/devices_controller.rb:40:in `update_pods'

Comment: I added those lines of code, do you have Idea why it is so ?:(

Comment: Ok it works now , but it adds whole page under select tag , not only options.... I am going to create one more question , so it will not confuse people

Comment: Oh add `render :layout => false` to your controller's update_floors action to get rid of layout.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your controller,

You have not mentioned the respond_to js block any where in the code,

Just put this code in both update methods,

```
respond_to do |format|
 format.js
end
```

Comment: I suggest you to inspect the ajax request and reply from firebug, as well the web log. format.js block is necessary condition for rails app to respond to ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Give the response format in the controller `respond_to :js, :only=>[:update_floors,:update_pods ]` 
Apart from that write the following into `update_floors.js.erb` file.

`$('#floors_select').html("<%= escape_javascript(collection_select(:your_object_name, :floor_id, @floors.to_a, :id, :name, :prompt=>"Select a Floor")) %>");`


I think the above will work.

Comment: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms

TypeError ({:only=>[:update_floors, :update_pods]} is not a symbol):
  app/controllers/devices_controller.rb:35:in `update_floors'

Comment: May I know where have you written the above line?

Comment: devices_controller.rb 


` def update_floors
    # updates floors and pods based on genre selected
    site = Site.find(params[:site_id])
    # map to name and id for use in our options_for_select
    @floors = site.floors.map{|a| [a.name, a.id]}.insert(0, "Select a Floor")
    @pods   = site.pods.map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}.insert(0, "Select a Pod")
     
    respond_to :js, :only=>[:update_floors,:update_pods ] 
  end`

Comment: update_floors.js.erb

`$('#floors_select').html("<%= escape_javascript(collection_select(@floors, :floor_id, @floors.to_a, :id, :name, :prompt=>"Select a Floor")) %>");
$('#pods_select').html("<%= escape_javascript(options_for_select(@pods)) %>");`